# autoplot with seas function for seasonal decomposition produces error subscript out of bounds

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, stl-decomposition

I'm trying to use the `seasonal::seas()` function to do a seasonal decomposition on my time series data and plot the results. Wrapping the `autoplot()` function around `seas()` usually works great but for the data below I am getting an error. I have seen some posts with subscript out of bounds errors around seasonal decomposition but none that have fixed the issue. The `seas()` function has the warning `Model used in SEATS is different: (1 1 2)` but I dont know why that would cause an error. Any help in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

The code:

```
library(forecast)
library(seasonal)

data <- c(11666, 18526, 14955, 13791, 13508, 15682, 23039, 24190, 23628, 23411, 25068, 20204, 16084, 15726, 13677, 14668, 17915, 25673, 30529, 31990, 31334, 30129, 24323, 19584, 20827, 19766, 21886, 25119, 31832, 31032, 26647, 28725, 26160, 22611, 20698, 21711, 20014, 21698, 27068, 27181, 23442, 25894, 22482, 21894, 20365, 20078, 20995, 22959, 25745, 33074, 29875, 27740, 29499, 27302, 19854, 19658, 20850, 20130, 21415, 25808, 35240, 31326, 31128, 29594, 25660, 26359, 25723, 26995, 25283, 26823)

time_series <- ts(data, freq=12, start=c(2013, 10))
autoplot(seas(time_series))
```

Produces the error:

```
Model used in SEATS is different: (1 1 2)
Error in `[.default`(object$data, , c("trend", "seasonal", "irregular")) : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs because the decomposition has no seasonal component and `autoplot()` is assuming that it does.

I've now updated the dev version of the package (https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast) to allow this case.